# How should I test this particular material-ui component?

Tags: reactjs, testing

```
<speedDial sx={{margin:3}}
 arialabel="Additional Action"
 direction="right"
 icon{<speedDialIcon openIcon={<EditIcon/>}/>}>
 {actions.filter(action => action.show ===true).map((action) =>(
 <speedDialAction
 key={action.name}
 icon={action.icon}[enter image description here][1]
 tooltipTitle={action.name}
 onClick={action.handleClick}/>
 ))}
 </speedDial>
```

above is the mui component code of one of my component i need to perform a test cases on on one of specific speedDialAction. current there are may speedDialAction mapping so can anyone know how should i firevent on testcases on specific speeddialAction

Comment: With MaterialUI it helps to look at the code in their github repo to see what to target. They also have test so you can look at how they target things in their tests
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/packages/mui-material/src/SpeedDialAction 
it seems under the hood it is a ToolTip component